# Как получить dom-узел тэга, из которого через <script> запустился js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Скажем есть код

```
<section>
    <p></p>
</section>
<section>
    <p><!-- Сюда должно выводится сообщение --></p>
    <script>
        const currentParagraph /* = ? */;
        currentParagraph.textContent = "Текст для параграфа";
    </script>
</section>
```

Секции и параграфы не отличаются друг от друга. И мне нужно, чтобы код вывел текст для параграфа, опираясь на ту секцию, в которой он вызывается. То есть обычный `document.querySelector("section p")` не подойдет. Никаких id или классов добавлять нельзя, кол-во секций и их расположение неизвестно (то есть `querySelectorAll("section")[1].querySelector("p")` не подходит). Мне кажется, что если бы я смог получить ссылку на dom узел, из которого вызвался скрипт - это решило бы все проблемы. Можно ли это как то сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Document.currentScript возвращает элемент script, который выполняется в данный момент.

```html
<section>
  <p>1</p>
</section>
<section>
  <p>2</p>
  <script>
    document.currentScript.closest('section').querySelector('p').textContent = "Текст для параграфа";
  </script>
</section>
<section>
  <p>3</p>
</section>
```